# Correct use of the <small> tag, or how to markup "less important" text

Tags: html, semantic-markup

Yet another tag that was given new meaning in HTML5, `<small>` apparently lives on:

> http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/small.html#small
>
> The small element represents so-called “fine print” or “small print”,
>   such as legal disclaimers and caveats.

This unofficial reference seems to take it a little further:

> http://html5doctor.com/small-hr-element/
>
> `<small>` is now for side comments, which are the inline equivalent of
>   `<aside>` — content which is not the main focus of the page. A common
>   example is inline legalese, such as a copyright statement in a page
>   footer, a disclaimer, or licensing information. It can also be used
>   for attribution.

I have a list of people I want to display, which includes their real name and nickname. The nickname is sort of an "aside", and I want to style it with lighter text:

```
<li>Laurence Tureaud <small>(Mr.T)</small></li>
```

[image]

I'll need to do something like this for several sections of the site (people, products, locations), so I'm trying to develop a sensible standard. I know I can use `<span class="quiet">` or something like that, but I'm trying to avoid arbitrary class names and use the correct HTML element (if there is one).

Is `<small>` appropriate for this, or is there another element or markup structure that would be appropriate?

Comment: What happens if you want to use `<small>` somewhere else in your code without the lighter text? Then you might as well have went with the `<span>`, because you'd have to assign a class to each `small` then wouldn't you? I think the `<span>` is how most people would do it anyway.

Comment: @Ozzy: I'm totally fine with taking that chance. I'd rather code for the rule (most common usage), not the exception. Anyways, I would just use `<small class="quiet">`. That's more of a CSS issue than a markup one.

Comment: @Ozzy: or simply use inheritance, `#mainContent small` is, after all, different to `#mainContent > small` and `#footer small`.

Comment: @Ozzy The idea is use combinators: `#nav small { ... }`, `article small { ... }`, `.popup small { ... }`, etc.

Comment: I think you make an interesting case for `<small>` for that usage. However, I think that semantically, the parentheses are sufficient, (in the same way as there's no `<sentence>` element), and that therefore all you need is a hook for styling, in which case `<span>` is the appropriate element. Not an answer, because I'm not convinced there is correct answer here.

Comment: @Alohci: That was something I considered. I also considered adding the parentheses with :before/:after which didn't seem right, so I guess you could say the punctuation dictates the semantics. In all honesty, what I really wanted was a styling hook, like you said - but thought I might be able to take advantage of something better than span.

Comment: The right case for the <small> tag is with Bootstrap given here: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_typography.asp

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The spec you're looking at is old, you should look at the HTML5 spec:

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/

I suggest `<em>` here  instead of small:

```
<p>Laurence Tureaud also called <em>Mr. T</em> is famous for his role
in the tv series A-TEAM.</p>
```

`<small>` is not used commonly in an article sentence, but like this:

```
<footer>
    <p>
    Search articles about <a href="#">Laurence Tureaud</a>,
    <small>or try <a href="#">articles about A-TEAM</a>.</small>
    </p>
</footer>

<footer>
    <p>
    Call the Laurence Tureaud's "life trainer chat line" at
    555-1122334455 <small>($1.99 for 1 minute)</small>
    </p>
</footer>
```

Article sentence:

```
<p>
    My job is very interesting and I love it: I work in an office
    <small>(123 St. Rome, Italy)</small> with a lot of funny guys that share
    my exact interests.
</p>
```

Comment: Yes, your link gives an example of using it like `<dt>Single room <dd>199 € <small>breakfast included, VAT not included</small>`. In your first example, I'd agree that `<em>` is correct, but in the others `<small>` seems quite appropriate. Thanks a ton, this clears up a lot of confusion for me since nearly all of the examples I found were legal-related.

Comment: So just to clarify, in my exact example you think `<em>` makes more sense? I'm now thinking that `<small>` is indeed the correct choice. Both your examples I believe are correct. Your thoughts? In any case, I appreciate directing me to the correct resource so I can make an informed decision. ...and the humor was not lost on me, I'm just busy :) I'll be calling that life trainer chat line ASAP.

Comment: I don't think small is the correct choice in your case, because you are saying: `Laurence Tureaud, also known as Mr.T, is...` in a short way. Use `<em>`! it is related to the context. `<small>` is for unrelated text

Comment: I'm actually just listing people's names and addresses, it's not in a sentence context. The "nickname" is a way to disambiguate people with the exact same names. How does your last comment correlate with your example: `<small>($1.99 for 1 minute)</small>`. To me it seems very related to the surrounding text. I thought em was to emphasize text (the opposite of what I want).

Comment: it is related but not in a linear way, it is "aside"

Comment: I think I have a better understanding now, but in my particular context I'm inclined to think that the nickname is in fact "aside" content. Like `<p>Laurence Tureaud <small>(Mr. T)</small> is famous for his role...</p>`. You could remove the `small` text and not change the meaning, much like an `aside`

Comment: It is not aside, trust me. Pick a SUBJECT inside a PHRASE/SENTENCE then talk about it. If you need to talk to something that is not related or not linearly related to the phrase, use small or aside.

Comment: Using `em` surely does not make the text appear lighter in any sense, but in italic. And to those who swear by “semantic HTML”, it means *emphasis* in some sense – rather the opposite of what the question asks for.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would think `<small>` would not be the correct tag for this as it suggests the text will be physically smaller which doesn't seem to be the case with your example. I think using a `<span>` would be more appropriate or possible the HTML `<aside>`. http://dev.w3.org/html5//spec-author-view/the-aside-element.html

Comment: `<small>` **does not** mean it's supposed to be visibly smaller. That's the old-school presentational usage. `<aside>` is block level content, definitely not the right choice. It even says: *"It's not appropriate to use the aside element just for parentheticals, since those are part of the main flow of the document."* which is exactly what I'm doing.

Comment: Ah didn't think about `<aside>` being block level. Good point. I am aware that `<small>` doesn't strictly mean it will be visibly smaller I meant it is more likely to be thought that way as the w3.org description mentions 'small print' as an example. If `<small>` is going to be used for this I would suggest combining it with it's own class as mentioned in the comments above.

Comment: @Madmartigan You mean that the phrase "small print" should not be taken literally?

Comment: @MrLister: What I mean is that you don't use `<small>` *just* to style something that you want to look small, and the way you actually style `<small>` doesn't matter (it can be big if you desire). This is strictly a markup question, not a CSS or presentation one. For an example, I'd expect a screen reader to (by default) read that part in a softer, quieter, or less emphasized voice (I know I can use aural stylesheets, just an example). Basically I'm looking for the opposite of `<strong>`, a way to de-emphasize part of a text (styling it is a separate issue). Hope I've made myself clear.

Answer (score -11):

You should ask yourself how you would prefer the document to be displayed when style sheets are not applied. Select the markup according to this, instead of scholarly or scholastic theories about “semantic markup” (see my [pragmatic guide to HTML](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/pragmatic-html.html8)).

If smaller size is what you want, then use `<small>` or `<font size=2>`. The former is more concise and easier to style, and it is more “resistant” (on some browsers, settings that tell the browser to ignore font sizes specified on web pages do not remove the effect of `small`). So it’s a rather simple choice.

On the other hand, font size variation inside a line of text is typographically questionable. In printed matter, it is much more often accidental, an error, rather than intentional. Putting something in parentheses is normally a sufficient indication of being somehow secondary

Comment: This is wrong. HTML elements should be used to convey semantic meaning, not presentation.